# How to right align section numbers using the rst2pdf stylesheet

Tags: restructuredtext, rst2pdf

I am using rst2pdf for converting an rst document. In the table of contents, I have the following

[image: left aligned numbering].

But I want the right aligned numbering, like the following

[image: right aligned numbering].

I am using the rst2pdf stylesheet for tableofcontents initialization. I didn't know how to adjust this alignment using the stylesheet or even at the rst format level.
The current configuration I set is:

```
.. contents:: Table of Contents
   .. sectnum::
   :depth: 2
```

I want the solution either at rst-level or at rst2pdf-level.

Comment: The [`toctree` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree) has only the `:numbered:` option with no styling option. You will need to apply styles, if possible, in the stylesheet.

Comment: @StevePiercy, Do you know how to make the right alignment for contents in stylesheet? I could not find the right option for the contents/tableofcontents classes.

Comment: No, I don't know anything about *TeX stylesheets. I would suggest searching the *TeX documentation first, then the SO community https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @StevePiercy, The stylesheet I'm using here is with respect to the reStructuredText(rst) file format. This supports only a subset of Tex formatting options. So, I wanted to know if the section-number right-alignment is possible with rst files. However, I looked for any inputs from Latex forum. Couldn't find solution from my search. All, Kindly help me find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the default stylesheet, I think this will pick up the `item-list` style, which is defined as:

```
    item-list:
      parent: bodytext
      commands: []
             [VALIGN, [ 0, 0 ], [ -1, -1 ], TOP ]
             [RIGHTPADDING, [ 0, 0 ], [ 1, -1 ], 0 ]
      colWidths: [20pt,null]
```

These `commands: []` are actually table styles ... check the docs for tables and that may help with how to align each column, try setting the `ALIGN` value, something like this (sorry I don't have an example handy)

```
[ALIGN, [ 0, 0 ], [ -1, -1 ], RIGHT ]
```

Comment: I was using the sectnum directive. having the ALIGN attr in item-list is not helping me to right-align the section numbers in the toc. The item-list class works for the jotting points, but doesn't work for the table of contents.